# NSDictionary Pass Between Classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to pass a NSMutableDictionary object between two classes. I've tried adding a method that returns a dictionary to no avail.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*) getResponse
{
return response; //where response is a dictionary that has keys and objects assigned
}
```

but even then the dictionary can not be pulled from the other class; it returns "null."

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your example... If `response` is defined in your class, this will return it. Make sure that the other class retains it!

Comment: There is one thing wrong with it: Its name. It should simply be `response` to conform to Cocoa naming conventions. A selector that starts with `get` should end with a colon, and the argument should be a pointer at which to store the gotten value (return-by-reference). This method is fine as it is, but should be named simply `response`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried adding a method that returns itself to no avail.
>
> ```
> -(NSMutableDictionary*) getResponse
> {
> return response;
> }
> ```

That's because this method returns a dictionary. For the method to return itself, it would have to ask the object `self` for its implementation for the method's selector, or ask the Objective-C runtime to return the `Method` structure.

But that's not what you actually want to do, is it?

If you mean for this method to return the response dictionary, well, that's exactly what it does. It is correct as written (aside from its name, as I already explained in my comment on the question).

> … but even then the data can not be pulled from the other class;

The method does not claim to return a data object; it claims to return a dictionary object. If it did return a data object, that would be a bug.

> … it returns void.

No, it returns `NSMutableDictionary *`. `void` is a type; it makes sense in no other context.

If you meant it returns `nil` (the pointer to no object), then that means you didn't have a response dictionary to return. Don't ask this object for the response until it has one.

You may want to make the object that wants the response the delegate of the object that holds the response, and have the response-holder send a message to its delegate when the response comes in. You may even include the response in that message; the alternative would be that the response-holder passes only itself, and the delegate asks the response-holder for the response dictionary in its implementation of the delegate method.

More information:

- [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/)
- [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/)
- [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/) (including the explanation of delegation, but don't skip to that part)

Comment: I edited my question to make more sense. For some reason though, the variable seems to not be retained. I'll check through my code. Thanks.

Comment: @James Martinez: There's no reason in your code why it would be retained. You don't retain it in this access, so it will only be retained if the caller retains it. If you're referring to the original ownership of the dictionary in `response`, the getter is not the place to look for that: Look in the setter, or the original assignment to the variable or property. Note that assigning to a variable and assigning to a property are very different, as discussed in the Objective-C language documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If your method returns nil, it's because your `response` variable is nil.  It's likely not initialized at this point.  Try doing `NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);` within the getResponse method.  See if the console prints (null), or a valid NSMutableDictionary object.

Comment: It prints null, but it should already have information in it as it was previously declared and used.

Comment: Means that the variable was never set.  Memory retention isn't the problem here.  Your init / setter wasn't called before executing this method.  Or, you're executing it on a new object, instead of one that was init'd.

Comment: I have attached my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599955/cant-send-nsmutabledictionary-to-another-class